# web application firewall development

Tags: python, security, mod-security, apache-modules

I have an assignment to develop a web application firewall. I have been researching for some source codes about that.My main source was ModSecurity.

Main question is that:

-Which framework or programming language I can use, to develop a web application firewall? Which one would be the most useful?

-Can I use Django & Python?

It would be a starting point for the project research.

Comment: What is a "web application firewall"? I know what a web application is, and a firewall, but the combination makes no sense.

Comment: think about what you want to block / allow. that's what mainly a firewall does!

Comment: i also require codes for web application firewall. anyone find any link in google?

Comment: No, I don't know @Novikov. I researched many resources but there wasn't a clear answer about it.There are many resources but it isn't explained clearly in which language I have to code it.

Comment: @Lennart et al: There are a number of WAF vendors out there now -- Imperva, Barracuda, F5, etc.  It's basically deep packet inspection on HTTP/HTTPS traffic to further identify legitimate vs. malicious traffic.  A cross between a firewall and an IDS, but targeted at web threats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so my guess was basically correct, although I thought it was protecting an app with no or bad security, but it's more about protecting against attacks. In that Case, Django is definitely wrong. It's clearly doable in Python, but don't expect to be able to handle 100.000 requests per second. :) But if it's research and development, I think Python can be a great choice, as it's fast to develop in, and with tools like Cython it can be quite fast to run as well. Should you then end up making a finished product that *does* need extreme performance, you can take the algorithms and translate them to C/C++.

I'd look into Twisted in your case. That may be the correct solution.

---

"It will be used on the server side to control the user transactions via HTTP."

Most web application frameworks have security settings. These are usually not called "firewalls", and you didn't answer my questions, so I'm going to guess here:

You are writing a web proxy that will act to filter out requests which do not have the correct permission because there is an application which does not have any access control at all. Is this correct?

Yes, you can do that in Python. Django is probably not the correct solution. If you need to implement access control with login pages and user management, then you probably want SQL and templating and a lightweight Python framework could be helpful. Otherwise Twisted or just doing it with the functionality in standard lib might be the correct solution.

Comment: And why the downvote? My guess wasn't that far off, and the answer is pretty much correct.

Comment: I will try to explain it by the example of Mod Security.

-It is an Apache module whose purpose is to tighten the web application security.

-It can be used embedded in web server.It is an intrusion detection and prevention system.

-Basically, it analyses the incoming requests and filters them.

-It can be used against URL manipulation,back-end authentication, session hijacking, XSS attacks,SQL Injection,buffer overflow etc. -It has a method called "virtual patching" that controls the requests I guess.

By the way; how I can develop it, in which language.

I'm sorry but I didn't downgrade it.

Comment: I have just registered in SO.I don't have enough reputation to downgrade the answers.I think some others have done it. Sorry for that.

Comment: @OK, so my guess was basically correct, although I thought it was protecting an app with no or bad security, but it's more about protecting against attacks. Answer updated.

Comment: Not sure what's up with the seemingly random downvotes but here's +1 to compensate.

Comment: http://goo.gl/HBD0Z

I found a tutorial here to write a module for Apache server. It seems like I can code it in C. I want to ask that: "is it possible to code Apache modules in Python? Could it be efficient to use Python?"

Comment: It is just an academic research development for now,after that I will look for Cython for better performance.And as you adviced; I will take a look at Twisted. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

this is what you need to do, for start use Linux, much easier to handle then Windows, you have 2 options, the first is to implement NetFilter driver by hooking to the system calls (More Complex!) , the second is to use libnetfilter_queue library and iptables to transfer the packet to a user space application, the main idea is to do deep analysis to the payload beside checking the IP and TCP header, very similar IDS,IPS systems but it's focusing on web application security holes.

i don't think you can do this with python without deeper interfering, what you asking here is pretty tricky, it's involved the lowers levels of the system...

you can start analyze the data using this example:

configure the iptables

```
#: iptables -A INPUT  -j NFQUEUE --queue-balance 0:3
#: iptables -A OUTPUT  -j NFQUEUE --queue-balance 4:8
```

queues 0 to 3 is for all inputs (better to divided to different queue, there is limit for packets the queue can hold),the other are for all outputs

writing application in C (the iptables transfer the packet from the kernel to user space)

filterQueue.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <string.h>

/* for ethernet header */
#include<net/ethernet.h>

/* for UDP header */
#include<linux/udp.h>

/* for TCP header */
#include<linux/tcp.h>

/* for IP header */
#include<linux/ip.h>

/*  -20 (maximum priority) */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

/* for NF_ACCEPT */
#include <linux/netfilter.h>

/* for Threads */
#include <pthread.h>

/* for Queue */
#include <libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h>

#define NUM_THREADS     15

pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

void printTCP(unsigned char *buffer) {

 unsigned short iphdrlen;

 struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
 iphdrlen = iph->ihl * 4;

 struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (buffer + iphdrlen
   + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

 int header_size = sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + tcph->doff * 4;

 printf("| Packet Type: TCP \n");
 printf("|-Source Port      : %u\n", ntohs(tcph->source));
 printf("|-Destination Port : %u\n", ntohs(tcph->dest));
 printf("|-Sequence Number    : %u\n", ntohl(tcph->seq));
 printf("|-Acknowledge Number : %u\n", ntohl(tcph->ack_seq));
 printf("|-Header Length      : %d DWORDS or %d BYTES\n",
   (unsigned int) tcph->doff, (unsigned int) tcph->doff * 4);
 printf("|-CWR Flag : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->cwr);
 printf("|-ECN Flag : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->ece);
 printf("|-Urgent Flag          : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->urg);
 printf("|-Acknowledgement Flag : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->ack);
 printf("|-Push Flag            : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->psh);
 printf("|-Reset Flag           : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->rst);
 printf("|-Synchronise Flag     : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->syn);
 printf("|-Finish Flag          : %d\n", (unsigned int) tcph->fin);
 printf("|-Window         : %d\n", ntohs(tcph->window));
 printf("|-Checksum       : %d\n", ntohs(tcph->check));
 printf("|-Urgent Pointer : %d\n", tcph->urg_ptr);
}

void printUDP(unsigned char *buffer) {
 unsigned short iphdrlen;

 struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
 iphdrlen = iph->ihl * 4;

 struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr*) (buffer + iphdrlen
   + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

 int header_size = sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + sizeof udph;

 printf("| Packet Type: UDP \n");
 printf("|-Source Port      : %u\n", ntohs(udph->source));
 printf("|-Destination Port : %u\n", ntohs(udph->dest));
 printf("|-UDP Length : %u\n", ntohs(udph->len));
 printf("|-UDP Checksum : %u\n", ntohs(udph->check));

}

char * getText(unsigned char * data, char Size) {

 char * text = malloc(Size);
 int i = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
  if (data[i] >= 32 && data[i] <= 128)
   text[i] = (unsigned char) data[i];
  else
   text[i] = '.';
 }
 return text;

}

u_int32_t analyzePacket(struct nfq_data *tb, int *blockFlag) {

 //packet id in the queue
 int id = 0;

 //the queue header
 struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph;

 //the packet
 char *data;

 //packet size
 int ret;

 //extracting the queue header
 ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(tb);

 //getting the id of the packet in the queue
 if (ph)
  id = ntohl(ph->packet_id);

 //getting the length and the payload of the packet
 ret = nfq_get_payload(tb, &data);
 if (ret >= 0) {

  printf("Packet Received: %d \n", ret);

  /* extracting the ipheader from packet */
  struct sockaddr_in source, dest;
  unsigned short iphdrlen;

  struct iphdr *iph = ((struct iphdr *) data);
  iphdrlen = iph->ihl * 4;

  memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
  source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;

  memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
  dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;

  printf("|-Source IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr));
  printf("|-Destination IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
  printf("|-Checking for Protocol: \n");

  if (iph->protocol == 6) {
   printTCP(data);
  } else if (iph->protocol == 17) {
   printUDP(data);
  }

  printf("|-Extracting Payload: \n");

  char * text = getText(data, ret);

  //filtering requests for facebook
  if (text && text[0] != '\0') {
   printf("\n %s \n", text);
   ret = strstr(text, "facebook");
   if (ret == 0)
    //not found in string
    *blockFlag = 0;
   else
    //found in string
    *blockFlag = 1;
  }

  //release the packet
  free(text);


 }
 //return the queue id
 return id;

}

int packetHandler(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg, struct nfq_data *nfa,
  void *data) {

 printf("entering callback \n");

 //when to drop
 int blockFlag = 0;

 //analyze the packet and return the packet id in the queue
 u_int32_t id = analyzePacket(nfa, &blockFlag);

 //this is the point where we decide the destiny of the packet
 if (blockFlag == 0)
  return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
 else
  return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_DROP, 0, NULL);



}

void *QueueThread(void *threadid) {

 //thread id
 long tid;
 tid = (long) threadid;


 struct nfq_handle *h;
 struct nfq_q_handle *qh;
 char buf[128000] __attribute__ ((aligned));

 //pointers and descriptors
 int fd;
 int rv;
 int ql;


 printf("open handle to the netfilter_queue - > Thread: %d \n", tid);
 h = nfq_open();
 if (!h) {
  fprintf(stderr, "cannot open nfq_open()\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 //unbinding previous procfs
 if (nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error during nfq_unbind_pf()\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 //binding the netlink procfs
 if (nfq_bind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error during nfq_bind_pf()\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 //connet the thread for specific socket
 printf("binding this socket to queue '%d'\n", tid);
 qh = nfq_create_queue(h, tid, &packetHandler, NULL);
 if (!qh) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error during nfq_create_queue()\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 //set queue length before start dropping packages
 ql = nfq_set_queue_maxlen(qh, 100000);

 //set the queue for copy mode
 if (nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "can't set packet_copy mode\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 //getting the file descriptor
 fd = nfq_fd(h);

 while ((rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) && rv >= 0) {
  printf("pkt received in Thread: %d \n", tid);
  nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
 }

 printf("unbinding from queue Thread: %d  \n", tid);
 nfq_destroy_queue(qh);

 printf("closing library handle\n");
 nfq_close(h);

 return NULL;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 //set process priority
 setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -20);

 int rc;
 long balancerSocket;
 for (balancerSocket = 0; balancerSocket < NUM_THREADS; balancerSocket++) {
  printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", balancerSocket);

  //send the balancer socket for the queue
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[balancerSocket], NULL, QueueThread,
    (void *) balancerSocket);

  if (rc) {
   printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
   exit(-1);
  }
 }

 while (1) {
  sleep(10);
 }

 //destroy all threads
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django is a web application framework.  I don't see anyone writing a firewall implementation using it.

Comment: It is not a client side firewall application. It will be used on the server side to control the user transactions via HTTP. ModSecurity has a rule set called CRS(Core Rule Set).But I couldn't understand it exactly in which language they are written.Thank you for the link.

Comment: I have just registered in SO.I don't have enough reputation to downgrade the answers.I think some others have done it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Link is no longer accessible and even archive.org has no history of that

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is just some kind of academic exercise and Python helps you get it done fast, I don't think a high level language like Python is the best choice for a firewall (I don't even know if it's possible honestly). If you're planning some sort of proxy/filter application, that might be fine, but Django isn't needed either way.

Comment: Can it be a module for Apache server? How can I code a module for Apache Server?

Comment: There is documentation on the apache website about how to make modules for Apache. I don't know if you can write them in Python.

Comment: thank you for the answers.I have just found some useful documentation about it.It seems like; it is possible to write modules for Apache in Python.

Answer (score 0):

C, C++, Golang, Lua are all optional languages to develop a Web Application Firewall or Gateway, but django is not suitable for it. 
C, C++ can develop nginx plugin or backend WAF. 
Golang can develop gateway with WAF, such as Janusec Application Gateway. 
Lua can extend nginx access control and work as a WAF.